Implementing closures and performance impacts of, for instance, relative vs absolute jump
I was learning about closure conversion in my compilers class a little while ago, and wondered how much of a performance overhead there is to calling a closure vs. a function.
Consider a function returning a closure which takes zero parameters (so no variable captures), and the only difference is that calling said closure would be a jump to an absolute address, as opposed to a relative address for calling a function which is translated to a label.
Does absolute jump have any performance overhead compared to a relative jump? As an example, is bx Rm slower than b label in ARM64 processors?
Assume that location jumped to has already been cached in both cases.

I don't think you are asking about relative vs. absolute. I think you are asking about direct vs. indirect. In a direct jump, the destination is encoded in the instruction. In an indirect jump, the destination address is in a register or in memory.

taken as the single instruction, the relative requires going through an adder.  Both require a register read although the register address may be from a register file where the other is likely from one of the program counters.  So the relative may be a smaller percentage of a clock cycle.  Both will save the result somewhere an internal program counter, likely not register file.

There are much longer paths in timing closure than these.  So your overall max clock speed are not driven by either of these.

The register file access may affect other instructions around this one.  And if you take this out of context of the one instruction (yes, this is also pipelined so some of these steps are across multiple clock cycles already).  In order to use a register based branch means somewhere else there was one or more instructions to put that address in that register where the pc relative the relative value is an immediate in the instruction, having no other systemic cost.

you mention caching of the address or data, and that is only one part of the memory side, you have the branch predictor caching that takes time and even if cached it takes time.  I dont know if any of the arm64 cores/architecture can take instructions out of already fetched buffers,  obviously if executing linearly but what if branching?  .... if you want to get into talking about caching.

you would need to provide a set of real examples to discuss as this is far too broad and covers far too many topics as asked.  Also remember arm sells cores not chips, and performance has not been processor bound for a long time now.  The specific chip vendors ip and other purchased ip heavily weight into the overall performance, and one binary may perform dramatically differently on one chip than another with the same version of the same arm core being used.

Please consider a different SE site, such as: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

@ryanwebjackson: This is definitely not computer science; it's an engineering question about CPU performance and implementation details.  If it's on-topic anywhere on the network, it's here.  Seems ok to me.

Sorry if my question didn't seem clear enough, you're right I meant indirect jump, not absolute.
My assumptions are: location to jump to isn't the result of a previous condition, it's "always" been there, and the indirect jump has happened before. The location jumped to is also resident in instruction cache. Same goes for the unconditional relative jump.

We can look at function pointers, lambda, closures for some definitions of a closure.  We can see that the closure allows access to variables in the caller.  In pascal, you can pass by reference or by value.  The same is true in C++ with '&references'.  This is for a single value.  With a closure, the entire scope of the caller is accessible, yet it is defined by the implementation (what external references are needed).
We can take for example 'vtable' in C++ which is responsible for implementing inheritance overrides of a base class.  The 'vtable' is a table of function pointers referenced from the this pointer.  A derived object will have a vtable with different entries than the base class.
The example assembler you give is bx Rm and b label. This is really more like the C++ virtual method difference.  A virtual method is typically dispatched with bx Rm as opposed to a direct call.  The slow down is minimal and you can find a variety of references to 'C++ virtual function overhead'.

wondered how much of a performance overhead there is to calling a closure vs. a function?

If the closure can be bundled, it only needs to be passed as a data pointer.  So the access to variables is like ldr Rn, [Rclosure, #variable].  Then 'Rn' can be used like it was passed by value.  Typically, a function needs a stack frame, especially if register pressure is great.  I would imagine that languages generating assembler would arrange the function 'prologue' in the caller and it would set a stack frame and/or a variable 'vtable' that would allow access to the callers variables.  Just like the 'C++ virtual function overhead', the closure references should be on the same order (ie, very very minimal).
There is of course an additional store when the routine completes to update the caller's values.  stm Rclosure, {reglist}, may be possible in some cases and/or a compiler may do value analysis/SSA and decide to store the values upon 'completion' of any update.  So, it is most likely a load/store cycle for each closure variable used.

The OP has a point that bx Rm maybe related.  A 'thunk' can be to marshal the closure data for a common layout by the closure code.  It would then write back the data on a return.  Also, the first part of the message (and even some that follows), is naive.  We may have closures calling closures and different use cases.  Such cases may make coordination of caller and callee data layout next to impossible.  But certainly, it is a possible optimization for a single closure, including placement of closure data in registers.
In part it depends on what effort you place on the caller vs the callee/thunk.  If the caller can enforce some standard layout, then you can directly use that data in the closure.  This maybe next to impossible in practice, so a 'thunk' to marshal the data is probable.
Here the overhead is 2N*load/store + virtual dispatch.  We need to marshal the data from the caller to the closure layout on prologue.  The epilogue in the thunk will then need to marshal the data back.  Each marshal action needs 'n' (reference variables) to load/store.
Another alternate is to access all variables through a data pointer.  Here, the data just needs to be placed in a common table to make access to the 'n' variables.  It is then upto the callee to cache the values in registers and/or write back as needed.
Eg. In 'C' like notation.
 enum {char *, short *, int *} references;
 closure(references data[n], arg1, arg2, ...);

Thunks have the advantage that they can be dynamically created.  Ie, the caller need not have information about the implementation of the closure and they can be generated at link time.  Also, The 'data pointer array' that I outlined can be built at build time, initialization time or lazily.  It would need a reference to the callers stack frame to access variables there (and would work from different call locations); instead of pointers, they would be offsets.
This would be a design choice between a global compile (lto) or  module building followed by linking (traditional compiles).  The data pointer method is most likely used as it minimizes coupling and needs only a little amended object information to achieve thunk generation.  You need additional infrastructure for type safety, which could be accomplished with mangling, rtti or many other mechanisms.

You're right that my description is very similar to a vtable jump in C++, but it's also applicable to closures.
Typically, a closure is constructed as a data pointer to an array that looks like this: [hoisted_function_ptr,  arg1, arg2, ...]
So calling a closure with no args (a thunk?) would look like
ldr Rm, [Rclosure, #]
bx Rm

If I'm not wrong. I'm asking about the performance overhead of such a function call, and how that might be optimized assume the function to jump to isn't constant propagated.

See addendum as a response.  There are many ways to implement this.  It is constrained by other issues with the framework.  For instance, if the tools are 'ABI' compliant.  Ie, we want an industry standard so different tool versions or completely different tools can interoperate, we have different demands.  Does the tooling support link time optimization (code generation) and how complex.  A thunk is a simple link time generation which you seem to demand of the tool; importantly this needs no information between caller and callee.  The 'data binding' is implement in a thunk using object info.

Ok I think this is the answer I was looking for, perfect. I really should've been more specific in my original question, as it pretained to compiler development. The specific scenario I was wondering about was a value-dependent closure, i.e., a closure returned by a function which you don't know the absolute location of at compile time. Of course, a JIT compiler could optimize the code to a direct jump by simply calculating offsets, but I was curious how much of an overhead first-class functions had in an ahead-of-time compiled language.

This brings to mind  'dynamic shared libraries'.  These often have 'thunks' called got/plt.  So, you can look at a shared library as a very large closure, with each process a 'caller'.  Ie. shared library overhead should be on the same order as closure overhead for 'aot' compiles.
